# Does compiler optimize inline function's local variables

Tags: c++, compilation

Now I am read the book `Inside The C++ Object Model` 's fourth section and have some question.

An inline function like this:

```
inline int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Then, a statement such as the following:
`a = max(x, y);`

this statement will transformed  to `a = (x > y) ? x : y;`

But the book say when add a local variables to the inline function like this:

```
inline int max(int a, int b)
{
    int maxval = (a > b) ? a : b;
    return maxval;
}
```

It will transformed to

```
int __max_lv_maxval;
a = (__max_lv_maxval = (x > y) ? x : y), __max_lv_maxval;
```

And obvious the function's performance will drop.

My question is Does the compile (such as VC2010,gcc) optimize the inline function and delete the local variables?

Comment: You make an unfounded assumption here: *And obvious the function's performance will drop*

Comment: Why is it "obvious" that performance would drop? C++ is a *language* with defined behaviour, not a guaranteed set of machine instructions. You should read another book, "Inside a good C++ compiler".

Comment: What those two said, plus the notion that it's complete folly to try to rationalise about this stuff. Just do your own job -- writing C++ code -- and let the compiler get on with its job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That book seems to be assuming the compiler inlines at a source level, this of course totally depends on the compiler. Most will begin inlining at the AST level, where transforms and certain optimizations can and will occur. This all assumes the compiler *will* inline the code.

If we look at your function, any *decent* compiler will turn them both into the same IR code, as it will compile the inline function before it is inlined, thus a temporary is required regardless (at IR level). when the IR is then actually inlined, the temporary will be folded away and instead replaced with the assignment destination of the call to `max`.

When we compile down to machine code, things can change even more, not only can temporaries be removed, but the destination will most likely be a register (in this case), which will have probably been used for on of the source operands as well.

**Bottom Line:**
This totally depends on your compiler, optimization levels and how it does variable livelyness analysis, value propagation and folding.

Answer (score 2):

Any interesting transformations we can do to the code, the compiler can do as well. And then some!

When the compiler can see that

```
inline int max(int a, int b) 
{
     return (a > b) ? a : b; 
} 

a = max(x, y);
```

can be transformed into

```
 a = (x > y) ? x : y;
```

It can also easily see that storing a value into a variable that is never used later, is meaningless. The store (and the variable) can be removed without changing the result of the program.

Local variables in small functions are often held in the CPU registers, and never stored in memory at all.

Comment: FWIW: It's not impossible that the compiler implicitly "defines" a local variable for each intermediate value, whether you write one or not.  And decides afterwards which local variables go into registers.  (This technique is particularly common for the ternary operator.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> inline int max(int a, int b)
> {
>     return (a > b) ? a : b;
> }
> ```
>
> Then, a statement such as the following: `a = max(x, y);`
>
> this statement will transformed to `a = (x > y) ? x : y;`

It's not that simple. `inline` is a hint, not a requirement. The keyword does change the rules slightly, but does not force inlining. You're also forgetting that `a` and `b` are *also* local variables to the `max` function, and the same book that assumes local variables cannot be optimized away assumes those local variables can be optimized away. They may be optimised away in those cases where it is safe to do so, or they might not be, depending on the compiler and compiler options. For running in a debugger, it may make more sense to keep them. They may *not* be optimised away when it is unsafe to do so, for example when `x` and `y` are `volatile`. In that case, `(x > y) ? x : y` reads one of them twice, which is a potentially visible, and therefore invalid, change in behaviour.

Comment: "Slightly". It completely changes the linkage of the function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm under the impression that `max` still has external linkage in the above example, exactly as without the `inline` keyword, and that the big change is that all translation units using the function must provide the same definition. (In C, `extern inline` and plain `inline` are not the same thing.)

Answer (score -1):

The compiler just do as you have show.
if we call this inline fun like this

```
void example()
{
  int m = max(10, 11);
}
```

the expansion will be

```
{
  int __max_lv_maxval;// mangled inline local variable  
 int m = (__max_lv_maxval = (x > y) ? x : y), __max_lv_maxval;
}
```

In general, each local variable within the inline function must be introduced into the enclosing block of the call
as a uniquely named variable. The GCC won't do more for you.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The language doesn't require the `inline` keyword to force inlining, it doesn't require the local variables to have unique names (if they continue to have names at all), and GCC will certainly do plenty more for you.

Comment: @hvd if the inline function expanded for multiple times , each expansion is likely to use its own local vars, the name will be like __max_lv_maxval_00, __max_lv_maxval01

Comment: @stuser974349 Consider `{ { int a = 3; } { int a = 4; } }` -- two different variables in the same function with the same name.